# ITextpdf doesn't work with Polish/Czech letters from html

Tags: java, file, pdf, itext

I have a problem with Polish/Czech letters. I want to generate a PDF from html with Polish/Czech letters, but in Linux it doesn't generate these letters. It just skips it like it doesn't exist. My code looks like this:

```
ByteArrayInputStream(process.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

I think something is missing on the server side, because locally everything works properly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @KJ thank you for your answer. Do you know how to change it? I set ISO-8859-1 but now questions marks are displayed.

Comment: If it works locally but not on the server, it will be hard to help you since the community needs a self-reproducible code sample. It's up to you to debug/find out differences between your local environment and your server environment. Meanwhile I strongly recommend switching to iText 7 since iText 5 (and `XMLWorkerHelper` is an iText 5 class) has been deprecated years ago)

Comment: @AlexeySubach I can't find itext ver 7 from maven repo only ver 5 is available

Comment: Can you take a look at https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-itext-7-for-java ?